# best way to prove reflexive , antisymmetric and transitive from hasse diagram?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So i got this problem
Given S = {1,2,3,4,6,8,12,15} and aRb <=> a | b

a. draw hasse diagram

b. prove that (S,R) is a poset .

so for the hasse diagram  i already know how to draw it .

what i wonder is problem b.
poset must be reflexive , anti symmetric and transitive . 
So best way to prove that its reflexive , anti symmetric and transitive from the Hasse Diagram ??

Comment: You can only draw a Hasse diagram with a poset, so what you are trying to do is backwards.  You must prove the properties directly from the definition of the relation.

Comment: i see . so i just need to prove  that aRb <=> a|b is a poset ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: okay thx man XD

Comment: You can't prove any of these properties from a Hasse diagram. E.g. Hasse diagrams don't show transitivity: if there are edges from $a$\to b\to c$ there *isn't* and edge $a\to c$. Similarly, the diagrams suppress reflexivity and can't show antisymmetry.

Comment: haha okay thx . i miss understood since the problem need us to draw hasse diagram first , so i thought i must prove by using the hasse diagram XD.

Comment: You could argue that since you are given a specific set, drawing the diagram proves that it is a poset. Or in other words: If it were not a poset then you couldn't obtain a hasse diagram in a). But if you end up with a hasse diagram and you checked all pairs of elements, then $(S, R)$ must be a poset. Note that this only works because $S$ is specified.